# Write a method to Read file that contains Int and strings into arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Write a method called UploadData to do this task. Choose the appropriate parameters and return type.

Input File Format:

Month Day Year Output

Sample Input File:

January 10 2018 236.9 January 11 2018 267.6 January 12 2018 278.1

Then I have to write another method that displays what has been read in .
This is what I have so far..

```
public static ArrayList<String> uploadData() throws IOException
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the name of the file");
    String fileName = keyboard.nextLine();
    ArrayList<String> List = new ArrayList<String>();
    File myFile = new File(fileName);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(myFile);

    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
        String n = scan.nextLine();
        scan.next();
        System.out.println(scan.next());
    }

    ArrayList<String> end = new ArrayList();
    return end;
}
```

Comment: Does your code work?

Comment: Yes but it prints out the data on one long line and not separated by dates .

Comment: What have you tried in order to separate the dates/data from each other? You will get better help by showing you have tried what you are asking for help on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use a [Regular Expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to split the values in a line. Try the following code:

```
public static ArrayList <String> uploadData() throws IOException {

  //this pattern can separate the string in multiple dates base on format of your example input file
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+ \\d{1,2} \\d{4} \\d{3}\\.\\d{1})");


  Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
  System.out.println("Please enter the name of the file");
  String fileName= keyboard.nextLine();
  // dateList is a better name than List
  ArrayList <String> dateList = new ArrayList <String>();
  File myFile= new File(fileName);
  Scanner scan = new Scanner (myFile);

  while(scan.hasNextLine()) {

    String n = scan.nextLine();
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(n);
    // each date thats matches the pattern will be added to the list
    while(matcher.find()) {
      dateList.add(matcher.group());
    }
  }

  for (String dateString: dateList) {
   System.out.println(dateString);
  }

  return dateList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This semi-pseudocode should help get you on the right track without me writing it for you. This method only works if the data is always perfectly structured like your sample input. It also may not be the best way :) but you can figure out any improvements that could be made.

```
uploadData
        ArrayList<Data> dataToPrint = ....

        while(input.nextLine)
            String line = input.getline
            String[] dataArray = line.split(" ") //split on space

            count = 1
            Data d;

            for(int i=0; i<dataArray.length; i++)
                if count == 1
                    d = new Data
                    d.setMonth(dataArray[i])
                if count == 2
                    d.setDay(...)
                if count == 3
                    d.setYear(...)
                if count == 4
                    d.setAmount(...)
                    dataToPrint.add(d)
                    count = 1
```

Data Class

```
Data
    String month
    int day
    int year
    float amount
```